# Flutter Firebase Error Null fundtion(FirebaseUser) cant assigned to parame,meter type FutureOr<dynamic>

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In my Firebase Authentication im am facing the Error:

> error: The argument type 'Null Function(FirebaseUser)' can't be
>   assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr
>   Function(AuthResult)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at
>   [authentication] lib\loginpage.dart:44)

if importet firebase_auth and flutter material

```
            onPressed: (){
              FirebaseAuth
              .instance
                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: _email,
                password: _password
              ).then((FirebaseUser user){
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
              })
                  .catchError((e){
                    print(e);
              });
            }
```

Comment: Issue looks to be here `.then((FirebaseUser user)` are you sure that the FirebaseAuth instance returns a FirebaseUser object?? Use the debugger breakpoint to see what it is returning.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code of the plugin the function

`.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

is a Future which return an AuthResult, so the problem is in your callback method

```
.then((FirebaseUser user)
```

should instead be

```
.then((AuthResult auth)
```

You can see it [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/e876d3ed840d09ca281a4e4ad5bfff0bf07fa903/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L219)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart#L148

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _email, password: _password)
                      .then((value) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                  }).catchError((e) {
                    print(e);
                  });
                },
```

try this it will work. if you have multidex error then refer this link
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#java